# Unable to retrieve subclass objects from table

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I am using this method to retrieve objects of type Burger from the AbstractMenuItem table. Note there are many classes extending AbstractMenuItem class and they are all stored in one table differentiated by discriminators.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<MenuItem> getBurgers() {
    return sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from AbstractMenuItem m where m.class=Burger.class")
            .list();
}
```

I get the following error when this method executes

```
   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: ''BU'.class' [from com.business.impl.AbstractMenuItem m where m.class=Burger.class]
```

Note that BU is the discrimator for Burger type.

How do i get around this?

Comment: why not use `from Burger`?

Comment: I aim to have a single method to retrieve subObjects based on a parameter i supply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

I used the following HQL. Works like a charm.

```
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from AbstractMenuItem m where m.class in ("
                            + itemType.toString() + ")").list();
```